# Product of two matrices A and B, such that columns of A are orthogonal to columns of B.

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-norm

Let $A$ and $B$ be $d \times n$ matrices, such that for each $1\leq i,j\leq n$, column $i$ of $A$ is orthogonal to the $j$-th column of $B$. Can we say something about $\|AB^T\|$? Here, $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the spectral norm. Also, assume that $n \leq d$.

Comment: Consider the special case where $A=\pmatrix{X\\ 0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0\\ Y}$. Then $\|AB^T\|=\|XY^T\|$. I don't think you can draw any conclusion about it other than $\|AB^T\|\le\|A\|\|B\|$.

Comment: I see. Thanks!!